# Add select option in DataText Field in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown, datatextfield

DataTable dtt = new DataTable();
adp = new SqlDataAdapter("Select ContractId,ContractNo From Contract Join Customer on Contract.Customer=Customer.CustomerId where Customer.EmailId='"+dropcustomer.SelectedValue+"'  ", con);
adp.Fill(dtt);
dropContract.DataSource = dtt;
dropContract.DataTextField = "ContractNo";
dropContract.DataValueField = "ContractId";
dropContract.DataBind();
dtt.Dispose();
adp.Dispose();
dropproduct.Items.Clear();

I Tried to show the -- Select--- Option in the DropDown list named dropContract but it is not Displaying